# Android: Sliding with ViewPager and highresolution pictures

Tags: android, android-viewpager, out-of-memory

I want to do horizontal sliding using the `ViewPager` functionality:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html

Everything is working fine but I get OutOfMemory-Exceptions because of the bitmap-Representation of the highres-Pictures. E.g. on a Sony Xperia S with the 12 MPixel Ie want to show on every Page 1 Picture a 3 MPixel.
=> 3 MPixel * 4 = 12MB of Heap for every Page

As far I know there is a minimum of 3 Pages 
( `setOffscreenPageLimit` min. is 1)

Therefore we have at least 36MB of heap used only for the pictures. This doesnt work :-(

Workaround is to lower the qualtiy of the pictures and load the highres on a new activity (e.g. webview).

Any other ideas? 
Is it possible to load low res pictures for the sliding and then the moment the user is touching the device a bigger pictures is loaded?
Sliding with another component?

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just load the picture for whatever page is active, and then when the user swipes to a different page, remove the image they were looking so it isn't using up the memory?

Comment: Good idea. But how should I do that? At the moment 3 Instances are automatically created from the viewpager and the image-load is done in onActivityCreated after creation. While sliding you can see the half of the picture from page 1 and half from page 2.

Comment: Not sure of the top of my head. See what Google comes up with, https://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=Android+Java+remove+image+from+memory